# Tab stuck on child element

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, tabindex

I have a div which has tabindex 0 and inside it there are child items with tabindex 0. I can't tab through children, it gets stuck on the first child. And I can't go back through shift + tab. Does anyone knows how to tab through children.

I tried changing the tabindex to -1, to change the tabindexes to 1 or 2, to work with on focus, on blur and stoppropagation.

Comment: Please add an [Minimal minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post. It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. See [How to add a StackOverflow snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: That *should* work. Why it doesn't work for you probably relates to your code - please post what you've done.